# How to go on live from sandbox mode in paypal express checkout php?

Tags: php, paypal

I have setup paypal express checkout system in my website from https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/

It's working fine in sandbox mode.

Now i would like to on live mode(Paypal). After change to

`$sandbox=false;`

I am getting the following exception:

`SetExpressCheckout API call failed. Detailed Error Message: Security header is not validShort Error Message: Security errorError Code: 10002Error` Severity Code: Error

Comment: i think the api string is different for production, check your online acct.

Comment: Okay, i will add the API string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Paypal site - you need the live API credentials. If you haven't set up a merchant account, that is your next step. If you have, the credentials will come from you account settings.

> Ready to Go Live?
>      Get a merchant account and generate API credentials. In your code:
>
> **THIS ==>** Replace the Sandbox API credentials with the live API credentials.
>      In the paypalfunctions.php file, make sure to set the Sandbox variable to false this causes the code to use PayPal live site API
>   endpoints.
>
> DO NOT hardcode your API credentials.  Manage your API credentials securely, such as loading the credentials from a secure key store or
>   some other secure configuration.